# Can I set specific time zone to Azure Functions app?

Tags: azure, timezone, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

Please let me hear your advice.

I played the setting of server time zone from UTC to specific time zone at azure web apps and it was good and changed as I expected specific time zone.
[PROCESS] App Setting : WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE = Tokyo Standard Time

Now, I want to use specific time zone within function app.
But, azure functions app is not settable like as web apps.
[reference link](https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/01/24/changing-the-timezone-on-your-azure-webapp-app-service-function/)

But, this ref link expressed like as it only effect on web apps [reference link](https://blog.shibayan.jp/category/Azure?page=1442365496)

Comment: This case was caused by the missing of right format usage. It can be solved by adding the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE at function app setting and then used the right format inside the calling function. I want to thanks to @Joy Wang for your participation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I set `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE = Tokyo Standard Time` in the Application settings in the portal and check the time in Kudu, it works fine.

[image]

Here is my function Application settings.

[image]

If you want to find Application settings, refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Update:**

> I call time inside function's coding (index.js) returned the UTC time.

If you do not specify the date format, the **Date** will out put as an [ISO Date Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript#iso-date-format), like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, actually the time has been changed to `Tokyo Standard Time` instead of the `UTC time`.

Comment: Yeah....I think that you mean 'web app' application setting, can you also test at 'functions app' application setting that was my problem place.

Comment: @KhinThet  No, this is a function app, please check my screenshot. If you want to access it, go to your function app in the portal -> Platform features ->Application settings , and you will find it.

Comment: Just I'm mad. I call time inside function's coding (index.js) returned the UTC time. :(

Comment: @KhinThet I have updated my answer, you could refer to it.

Comment: @KhinThet Sorry for my oversight, It seems so strange.

Comment: Ohh....just you used getDay() that makes me WoooW. Thanks for your updated answer.

Comment: Hey...I coded like that. ...............................................................................................................................................                                                                                     var fmtDate = current.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(current.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+current.getDate()).slice(-2);
 var fmttime = ("0"+current.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0"+current.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0"+current.getSeconds()).slice(-2); ====>   "fmtDate": "2018/06/15",
        "fmttime": "10:40:53",

Comment: Yeah....result was here............................................................................................................................................................................"fmtDate": "2018/06/15","fmttime":"10:40:53",

Comment: @KhinThet Glad your issue has been solved, actually it was caused by format, since I am not very familiar with js, I will modify my answer, thanks for your sharing.:-)

Comment: A point to NOTE: WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-time-zones) just in case someone else lands into this thread.

Answer (score 10):

to get the value for a `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` use PowerShell `(timezone).id` on your local PC. In my case I got "Romance Standard Time"