# Why is my Azure Function App Timestamp an hour less

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App that runs every five minutes. The document has a Timestamp field using

```
DateTime.Now
```

I live in the UK which is currently british summer time 26-09-18 which is 1 hour ahead of GMT. My Azure data centre is UK South. The timestamp is one hour wrong. E.G. 20:01 is stored in the documnt as 19:01. How can I correct this?

Comment: I'v tried Datetime. UtcNow and DateTimeOffset neither adjust timestamp to BST and I added the entry WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE  GMT Standard Time and W.Europe Time etc none change the timeStamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this in code, for the UK, you can use the following which should auto adjust for daylight savings.

```
TimeZoneInfo ukTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");

DateTime utcDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime ukTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, ukTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine(utcDate == ukTime);
```

On the 1st of January, the value of  `ukTime` should be equal to `UTC`, as the time zone used in the UK at that time of year is the `GMT` time zone which is equal to `UTC`.

[image: GMT]

---

On the 1st of June, the time in the UK should be an hour ahead of `UTC`, as the UK will have switched over the the `BST` time zone during that time of year.

```
utcDate = new DateTime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
ukTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, ukTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine(utcDate == ukTime.AddHours(-1));
```

[image: BST]

Comment: That worked! Howver not sure what the .Dump() is? TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").Dump();

Comment: Ooops!... it's a function of an app called LINQPad which is like a scratchpad for C#, see the tables  in the images above? I use LINQPad to dump the state of any object using the `.Dump()` method to get those tables (and the state of any other object for that matter), just forgot to remove it prior to posting

Comment: That sounds very interesting!

Comment: That's just the tip of the iceberg, it does so much more and the premium edition of it is completely worth its price tag, has saved me countless hours over the years

Comment: When I read back into app from CosmosDb the hour is 1 our forward blimey !

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion you're saving to the db with the converted time zone and then, later on retrieval of the values saves, converting those values again which would put the time 1 hour ahead of BST. My advice would be to always always always store as UTC, and only convert it to local time when you need it.

Answer (score 5):

Azure Functions by default are UTC.

- For **Windows** add the setting **WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE** and set the value your TimeZone

  - Ex: **WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE = GMT Standard Time**
- For **Linux** add the setting **TZ** and set the value to your Timezone

  - Ex: **TZ = Europe/Lisbon**

For **Windows** TimeZone values check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)?WT.mc_id=personal-blog-marouill#time-zones)
For **Linux** TimeZone values check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Still have a 3 hours difference, maybe I need to change time zone for storage too? As functions use storage

Answer (score 3):

The idea of serverless code is to abstract away where your code is physically running. Because of this, Azure Functions default to UTC time. You can set the local time zone by adding an `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` as your local time as an app setting. See [Can I set specific time zone to Azure Functions app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851519/can-i-set-specific-time-zone-to-azure-functions-app).

Comment: Though this setting exists, you should generally not use it. Instead handle it in code.  `DateTime.UtcNow`, `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, etc.

Comment: Yea but there isn't a code for UK... only GMT which as I said is an hour behind British Summer Time

Comment: @MattJohnson I agree. Also, using DateTimeOffset rather than DateTime will alleviate a lot of timezone issues since it's actually is aware of it's timezone.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow does not change the document timeStamp I checked it.