# Azure functions difference between CRON and execution (machine is on good time) - Do I need to "reset" storage account or change storage time zone?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

After noticing the time zone parameter in configuration was different for Linux machines thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61921251/5466477). We could adjust the time zone of the machine.

But that difference was only a 2 hours difference, and the function is triggered with a 5 hours difference compared with the cron.

The function: A Linux machine, the runtime version it's 3 and it's an App Service Plan.

I know the Azure Storage it's used by Azure Function timer triggers :

- does the storage have a "time zone"?
- Where is this "time trigger" in the storage so I can go and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this  One, we can change our trigger’s CRON Expression to represent the time in UTC .

The second way is to tell Azure Functions in which time-zone they should interpret the CRON Expression.

For an example , a man of the best Coast, it involves setting the  `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`  environment variable to  `Eastern Standard Time`. If you are on the lesser Coast, you may need to set yours to  `Pacific Standard Time`.

Find the region on that list, set it in the  `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`, and Azure Function automatically set the correct Time Zone for your CRON expression.

As per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) :-

> The **Azure Storage Emulator is now deprecated**. Microsoft recommends
> that you use the
> [**Azurite**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite)
> emulator for local development with Azure Storage. Azurite supersedes
> the Azure Storage Emulator. Azurite will continue to be updated to
> support the latest versions of Azure Storage APIs. For more
> information, see [**Use the Azurite emulator for local Azure Storage
> development**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite).

Please refer this for  [Working with Timer-Triggered Azure Functions in C#](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/10/14/timer-triggered-azure-functions/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but the function has the good time zone, and with a Linux machine you set the time zone with `TZ` variable. The question is if the storage will use this function time zone because we still have a difference between execution and cron